# android facebook login web page not found

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

hi guys having some problems on some of my devices when trying to log in to Facebook on my app it works perfectly for me but on one of our test device it takes you to a web page not found

[image]

any ideas as to why this is happening

Comment: What does the log cat say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image you have shown, it is pretty clear that the device has no internet connected. The browser can't go and fetch `https://m.facebook.com` without internet. You need to check for network connectivity in you app before you call facebook login page. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android) SO thread for how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

turns out i just had to clear my cash and app data then it worked fine don't know what the real problem was but this is a quick fix hope it helps someone